# countdown timer with minutes and seconds

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

i create a countdown timer that go from 10 to 0. i create a uilabel that shows the counter in seconds. now i want the label to show the counter minutes and second, like that: 00:00.
how can i do that?
here is my countdowncode:

```
-(void)countdown
{
    countdownCounter -= 1;
    countdown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countdownCounter];

}

-(IBAction)strat:(id)sender
{
    countdownCounter = 10;
    countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self     selector:@selector(countdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using one time, and one label. Try using the following code:

```
int seconds = [countDown.text intValue] % 60; 
int minutes = ([countDown.text intValue] / 60) % 60; 
countDown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
```

Comment: and if i want a Tenth of a second also(milliseconds)?

Comment: @cnaaniomer see my edited answer, not 100% about this, but it should be as simple as converting the ints to floats and formatting them to show decimal places.

Comment: but now i get this error : invalid operands to binary expression float and float. what is the problem?

Comment: The % (modulo) operator only works on integers. You must be using a float somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Do it exactly the same way, just add another timer.

```
  countdownTimer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(countdown2) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)countdown2
{
    countdownCounterMinutes -= 1;
}

and change countdown to

-(void)countdown
{
    countdownCounter -= 1;
    countdown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%i", countdownCounterMinutes, countdownCounter];

}
```

Comment: there is no other way to do the whole timer in one label?

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who what the answer in the end i do it this way:

```
-(IBAction)start
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self     selector:@selector(updateTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)updateTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    currentTime -= 10 ;
    [self populateLabelwithTime:currentTime];
    if(currentTime <=0)
       [timer invalidate];
}


- (void)populateLabelwithTime:(int)milliseconds {
    seconds = milliseconds/1000;
    minutes = seconds / 60;
    hours = minutes / 60;

    seconds -= minutes * 60;
    minutes -= hours * 60;

    NSString * result1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", (milliseconds<0?@"-":@""), hours, minutes, seconds,milliseconds%1000];
    result.text = result1;

}
```

in viewDidLoad i set currentTime for the countdown time in milliseconds.
hope you understand...

Answer (score 0):

I formatted the numbers (from float)with mins and seconds
 it this way, thanks your answers helped. (hope this helps another)

```
   - (void)ticTimer
{
    self.current -= self.updateSpeed;
    CGFloat progress = self.current / self.max;
    [self populateLabelwithTimeFormatted:self.current];
     ///  TimeLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", progress];

    // * Time is over
    if (self.current <= self.min) {
        [self stop];
        _TimeLabelNode.text= @"time up!";
    }
}

- (void)populateLabelwithTimeFormatted:(float)time {
    //convert float into mins and seconds format
    int mytime = (int) _current;
    int seconds = mytime%60;
    int minutes = mytime / 60 % 60;

    NSString * result1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%02d",  minutes, seconds];
    _TimeLabelNode.text = result1;
}
```